# Partial re encryption in AES-GCM mode in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I want to encrypt and decrypt file with AES. I know how to entirely encrypt and decrypt a file but sometimes I just want to manipulate a part of the file (for example with a RandomAccessFile).

I found some solutions to decrypt a part of a encrypted file with AES-GCM but my main problem is:

If I modify just a part of a file, **I need to re encrypt this new part. For performance reason, I don't want to re encrypt the whole file.**

**It is possible to just re encrypt the block of bytes where changes has been done in the file?**

Comment: I assume you mean AES-GCM, I don't know what AES-GSM means. GCM mode is an authenticated encryption mode which computes a MAC over the entire plaintext contents. As such this is very much the wrong mode to do the sort of thing you're doing. In order to do this you would basically have to decrypt the entire file just recompute the MAC on the part you changed. The output of the MAC is often referred to as the *tag* in discussions about authenticated encryption.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that if my file is very small, it is not really a problem to decrypt the entire file and encrypt again with changes. However, if my file is very big and I want just edit some bits of it at the middle of the file, recompute the encryptation is very not efficient and slow.
My alternative is to "cut" my file into blocks of 128bits, and cipher each block independently. If I do this method, I will use AES-CBC and I will define an IV that I will use for all 128 blocks of the files, but I don't know if it is really secure.

Comment: I use GCM mode because I saw that is secured mode thanks to the Tag. However, if I use the CTR mode, I think I can decrypt and encrypt just a part of the file, howevere CTR is malleable

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk+ You must _read_ the whole file (ciphertext) to verify the MAC before you can safely decrypt any part; having done that it is algorithmically possible -- though not with the Java API -- to compute the modified ciphertext portion, and to compute the new MAC (tag) using only the regenerated (or decrypted) old tag, the XOR of the old and new ciphertext, and its position in the file. But doing this allows 'two-time pad' attacks on confidentiality like crib dragging, and directly leaks the auth key allowing forgery, thus making your encryption worthless, so don't do that.

Comment: You don't need to break into single blocks; if you can break into chunks of something like 1k-10k bytes -- either at application-relevant boundaries, or arbitrarily -- that should give a good tradeoff between overhead and efficiency. (Using CBC with fixed (key and) IV on one-block data is effectively the same as using ECB with an offset, and subject to all the attacks on ECB like duplicating and reordering.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, create chunks can be a good alternative. I also see that CTR mode is GCM mode without MAC and allow random access in the cipher text if we know the counter. Therefore, CTR mode can be a good solution to my problem or it is also not safe?
Maybe the real question must be: In which case we can use CTR mode?